# how can I get date in presto sql

Tags: sql, presto

I have a code below but it throws an error.
How do I get the date 12 weeks from 2018-01-01 and use the case statement?

```
select
case when
date between cast('2018-01-01' as date) and DATE_ADD('week',12,cast('2018-01-01' as date)) -interval '1' day
then 'in 12 weeks' as period
from aaa limit 1
```

Comment: and the error is???? normally there would be an `end` before the `as period`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No error message will be displayed in athena..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `case` statement misses closing `end`:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       (DATE '2018-01-03'),
       (DATE '2018-04-04')
 ) AS t (date))


SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN date BETWEEN Cast('2018-01-01' AS date) AND date_add('week', 12, cast('2018-01-01' AS date)) - INTERVAL '1' day 
      THEN 'in 12 weeks' 
  END AS period 
FROM 
  dataset 
LIMIT 
  1
```

Comment: Error message is none.

Comment: @SJW query in the answer works fine for me (using Athena to test).

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this when the date column to be retrieved is varchar? thanks

Comment: @SJW depending on the format you need either cast is (as you do in the `BETWEEN`) or parse it (for example with [`date_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse)).

Comment: the date column is string.. I tried cast but didn't work...:(
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN cast(date BETWEEN Cast('2018-01-01' AS date) AND date_add('week', 12, cast('2018-01-01' AS date)) - INTERVAL '1' day) as varchar
      THEN 'in 12 weeks' 
  END AS period 
FROM 
  dataset
LIMIT 
  1

Comment: @SJW it is another question. Also it shoud be something like `cast (date as date) BETWEEN` not `cast(date BETWEEN .....`.